# How to refresh XmlDataProvider when XML file that is located on a server has been updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xmldataprovider

In Below code: Is there any way to update ComboBox.Items automatically when I update myXml.xml?

I know if 'myXml.xml' was local, I could use `FileSystemWatcher` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881755/refresh-combobox-when-xmldataprovider-is-updated). but how about this one?

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider Source="http://www.mywebsite.com/myXml.xml" 
              x:Key="myXml"  XPath="/data/names"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myXml}}"
              DisplayMemberPath="@name"/>
```

Comment: I don't think You can do this on HTTP got file. You could watch it yourself by polling it, but it looks like an ugly solution. You may try and access it via shared path (\\server\path\file) ?

Comment: FileSystemWatcher works on network drives and remote computers: see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/35b8bd4c-c377-4480-a9ed-96623e706dfb